# jQuery UI. Do a function after Block UI load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery BlockUI plugin.

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

I want to alert after jQuery BlockUI finished loading.

Here  is the code;

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#mymessage'),
    });
    alert("hi");
});
```

But the alert happens 1st and UIBlock loads 2nd. How can I fix this?

Here is the live demo http://jsfiddle.net/yHCjF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `onBlock` callback?

```
$.blockUI({
    message: $('#mymessage'),
    onBlock: function() {
        alert('loaded');
    },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yHCjF/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setTimeout()`.

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#mymessage'),
    });
    setTimeout(function(){ alert(); }, delay);
});
```